# Water Waves implementation in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I am developing a game(cocos2d+box2d), where I want to implement waves similar to below link,
http://jayisgames.com/cgdc8/?gameID=7
The above game done it using World Construction Kit for flash.

Is there any one ported similar thing to cocos2d, or any one knows how can i achieve similar using cocos2d, Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this tutorial will help you:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3888/how-to-create-a-game-like-tiny-wings-part-1